# How to get Jframe to work with mouse clicks?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener, gridworld

I am Making a connect four game in gridworld, if you are familiar with that, but my teacher told us absolutely nothing about mouse clicks, and the connect four pieces need to be placed in the column i click in, but i cant figure out what to add a mouse listener to so i made a Jframe to do it but i cant get that to work.

*So i need to know what to do to make the mouse clicks work to print the x and y coordinates of the click.*

```
public class ConnectFourWorld extends World<Piece> implements MouseListener
{
   private String whosTurn;
   private boolean gameOver;
   private String winner;
   Piece X = new Piece("ex", Color.WHITE, Color.RED);
   Piece O = new Piece("oh", Color.YELLOW, Color.BLUE);
   Location column1 = new Location(5, 0);
   Location column2 = new Location(5, 1);
   Location column3 = new Location(5, 2);
   Location column4 = new Location(5, 3);
   Location column5 = new Location(5, 4);
   Location column6 = new Location(5, 5);
   Location column7 = new Location(5, 6);

   public ConnectFourWorld()
   {
    super(new BoundedGrid<Piece>(6,7));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(350, 300));
    frame.addMouseListener((MouseListener) this);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    winner="no winner";
    whosTurn="X";
    gameOver=false;
      setMessage("Welcome to Connect Four World!  - -  Click a spot - "+whosTurn+"'s                     turn.");           
   }

   public boolean locationClicked(Location loc)
   {
      Grid<Piece> grid = getGrid();
      if(grid == null)
        return false;
  ArrayList<Location> reset = new ArrayList<Location>();
  reset  = grid.getOccupiedLocations();


  if(grid.get(loc)!=null)
    return false;

  if(gameOver == true)
  {
      for(int i=0; i<reset.size(); i++){
          grid.remove(reset.get(i));
      }

     gameOver = false;
     winner = "no winner";
       setMessage("Click a spot - " + whosTurn + "'s turn.");
    return true;
  }
  // Create a new location variable = add a piece
  Location place = new Location(0,0);
  place = addPiece(loc);
  if(place.equals(null))
      return false;
  //if location variable is = to null return false
  //call the get winner method and step method
  getWinner(loc);
  step();


  return true;  
   }

   public Location addPiece(Location loc)
   {
    Grid<Piece> grid = getGrid();
   if( grid == null)
  return null;  



 int col = loc.getCol();
 int row = grid.getNumRows() - 1;
 Location spot = new Location(row, col);
 ArrayList<Location> occ = new ArrayList<Location>();
 boolean taken = false;
 occ = grid.getOccupiedLocations();
 for (int i=0; i<occ.size(); i++){
     if(spot.equals(occ.get(i)))
         taken=true;
 }
 //loop that runs as long as location is valid and location is not null
    // move up in the row and add the new Location to that row and col
 while((!spot.equals(null))&&taken==false){
     for (int i=0; i<occ.size(); i++){
         if(spot.equals(occ.get(i)))
             taken=true;
     }
     row++;
 }
 //add a piece to that location and return the location
 if(whosTurn.equals("X"))
     grid.put(spot, X);
 else if(whosTurn.equals("O"))
     grid.put(spot, O);
 return spot;
   }

   //This method is done
public void step()
   {  
    Grid<Piece> grid = getGrid();
    if (grid == null)
       return;
      if(!winner.equals("no winner"))
        {
          setMessage("And the winner is..... " + winner + "\n Click anywhere on board to play again.");
               gameOver = true;

   }
}

    //This one is done   
   public boolean isWorldFull()
   {
    Grid<Piece> grid = getGrid();
       if(grid == null)
       return false;

    ArrayList <Location> list = grid.getOccupiedLocations();
     return (grid.getNumCols() * grid.getNumRows() == list.size());
  }


   public void resetWorld()
   {

   }

   public String getWinner(Location loc)
   {
    return "";
   }
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x=e.getX();
        int y=e.getY();
    System.out.println(x+","+y);
...
```

I have separate main class that is going to run this

Comment: You pretty much already asked this question.

Comment: A simple [**Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have sufficed.

Comment: Your example, shows a frame wih a MouseListerner attached to it, but it would seem that this isn't where your game is actually attached to. What is World?

Comment: I hate it when teachers expect you to read javadocs and java tutorials!

Comment: World is in the gridworld case study, its just a class to make boundedgrids or unboundedgrids. you can look it up online

Answer (score 0):

Add a mouse listener

```
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println(arg0.getLocationOnScreen().x);
            System.out.println(arg0.getLocationOnScreen().y);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried doing it this way but i get errors about adding "EnumBody" at that last line.

Answer (score 0):

You must overwrite the GridWorld GUIController Class..inside the constructor their is an method called display.addMouseListener().  Pretty much just write your code in their.  I do believe that they store the Location that you clicked in the variable loc.  Pretty easy once you know.  To get the object just do parentFrame.getWorld().getGrid().get(loc)...pretty straight forward...hope that helps!